# Python script works in librarys examples folder, but not in parent directory

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi

I have a newbie problem.
I have a Raspberry Pi 2 computer. I connected DHT11 sensor to GPIO PIN 4. Next, I've installed Adafruit_DHT_python library by running setup.py file using command:

```
sudo ./setup.py
```

After installation i ran example from /examples folder by:

```
sudo ./AdafruitDHT.py 11 4
```

It works like charm. This scriptis using installed library by importing it:

```
import Adafruit_DHT
```

When i write my own code in examples folder - it works. When I execute this code from parent folder, it returns this error:

```
ImportError: No module named Raspberry_Pi_2_Driver
```

When I installed this library in my system, should it work from any location in file system?
Also, when i try to execute script in examples folder as normal user(it have all needed premissions), it returns this error:

```
ImportError: No module named Adafruit_DHT
```

Comment: You can check the system path by running `import sys` and `print sys.path` to see

Comment: sys.path returned ` ['/home/pi/gpio/Adafruit_Python_DHT/examples', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7'] `
So, i have to import using path from first entry?

Comment: You should also type those commands in the example file and see whether they are the same because you said the script works inside the example folders.

Comment: example file return one more entry:
`'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Adafruit_DHT-1.1.0-py2.7-linux-armv7l.egg'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue, just used import sys

import sys
sys.path.append("/home/me/mypy")

to the path of the Adafruit_Python_DHT module (replace "/home/me/mypy"). Basically, we just have to tell python where it is. Something isn't installing properly.